# php stdClass Object Print a value from it

Tags: php

I got an array in return from database

I need to echo value 24 from this

My array is:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(i.pk_i_id)] => 24 ) )
```

Comment: It would be easier if you ___aliased___ `COUNT(i.pk_i_id)`  in your SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Mark Baker aliasing the field is probably the best solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.pk_i_id) as cnt FROM ...
```

but from a purely technical perspective:

```
<?php
$o = getData();
print_r($o); // check: example data matches example data given in question

echo 'result: ', $o[0]->{'COUNT(i.pk_i_id)'};

function getData() {
    return array ( (object)array( 'COUNT(i.pk_i_id)' => 24 ) );
}
```

Most often you access a property of an instance by simply putting the identifier of that property after `$obj->`, e.g. `$obj->foo`.
But whenever you have an identifier you cannot just put as a literal in your code (e.g. because it contains characters that are forbidden in php as identifier as in your case, or because your identifier is not a literal but computed) you can use the form `$obj->{expr}`.